# MS Access Conditional Formatting - Apply formatting comparing 2 different records

Tags: ms-access, formatting, conditional-statements

We use MS Access to log test data.  I'm wanting to apply condition formatting to compare 2 different records.  Example: Record # 1 - Test result was 10.  Record # 2 - Test result was 15.  I want to apply formatting to check if record # 2 was +/- 5 of the previous record # 1.

I would like to apply formatting to my reports and to my form screens.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrxfZ.jpg)

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Is there always a column with consecutive numbers **without gaps**? Like the "Test" column in your example? Then it's feasible, but the concept of "previous record" generally isn't well suited for databases.